# how to specify on newman what port and host to run on

Tags: c#, postman, newman, command-line-tool, postman-newman

I'm trying to integrate Newman(postman CLI tool) in my app, and I want to run it first on the localhost on a specific port, and change it in accordance later on.
Any suggestions on how to do that with the CLI?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and reading a ton I've figured out the best and simplest way to do so:
just setting up the following environment variable "HTTP_PROXY" to whatever and then using it with newman:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:58833
newman run demo.postman_collection.json --env-var HTTP_PROXY --insecure
```

Now I can listen to the above port and see all of newman's requests being sent.

found my solution here:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-request/blob/master/README.md#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables